# How do I find out if a file name has any extension in Unix?

Tags: file, unix, sh, file-extension

I need to find out if a file or directory name contains any extension in Unix for a Bourne shell scripting.

The logic will be:

1. If there is a file extension
2. Remove the extension
3. And use the file name without the extension

This is my first question in SO so will be great to hear from someone.

Answer (score 4):

The concept of an extension isn't as strictly well-defined as in traditional / toy DOS 8+3 filenames. If you want to find file names containing a dot where the dot is not the first character, try this.

```
case $filename in
    [!.]*.*) filename=${filename%.*};;
esac
```

This will trim the extension (as per the above definition, starting from the last dot if there are several) from `$filename` if there is one, otherwise no nothing.

If you will not be processing files whose names might start with a dot, the `case` is superfluous, as the assignment will also not touch the value if there isn't a dot; but with this belt-and-suspenders example, you can easily pick the approach you prefer, in case you need to extend it, one way or another.

To also handle files where there is a dot, as long as it's not the first character (but it's okay if the first character is also a dot), try the pattern `?*.*`.

The `case` *expression* `in` *pattern* `)` *commands* `;; esac` syntax may look weird or scary, but it's quite versatile, and well worth learning.

Comment: To make it look less scary, you can use the optional `(` to delimit the pattern: `([!.]*.*)`. Yes, it's POSIX syntax and helps `vi`'s `%` by matching open and close parens. +1 for not forking!

Answer (score 0):

I would use a shell agnostic solution. Runing the name through:

```
cut -d . -f 1
```

will give you everything up to the first dot ('-d .' sets the delimeter and '-f 1' selects the first field). You can play with the params (try '--complement' to reverse selection) and get pretty much anything you want.

Comment: None of the other answers so far are specific to a particular Bourne-compatible shell. Or do you mean csh/tcsh/whatever?

Comment: OP specified Bourne (sort of), I meerly suggested a solution that does not care. So yeah, csh/tcsh/whatever.